# How do I pass a List<int> via FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#, .net, url, post, serialization

On the requester side my code looks like following

```
var myList = new List<int> {1,2,3};

var content = 
    new FormUrlEncodedContent
    (
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
        {
        KeyValuePair.Create("myList", myList.ToString())
        }
    );

//Make Post Request here
```

On the receiver end I want my controller method to be

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyMethod(List<int> myList)
{
    \\ Doing stuff here
}
```

---

Comment: are you using asp mvc ?

Comment: yes. I am using Asp mvc

Comment: Why just not to use JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to do:

```
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

var myPostData = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("myList", string.Join(",", myList))
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(myPostData);
```